# I need to exclude word from regular expression

Tags: regex

I have this regexp:

```
^[a-z0-9]+([.\-][a-z0-9]+)*$
```

I need exclude from match only one word "www".
I tried the negative lookahead but without a success.

Comment: What way are you applying your regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead like this:

```
^(?!www$)[a-z0-9]+([.-][a-z0-9]+)*$
 ^^^^^^^^
```

This will not match a string equal to `www`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cH0nY3/1)

If you want to fail a match with strings that contain `-www-` or `.www.`, use

```
^(?!.*\bwww\b)[a-z0-9]+([.-][a-z0-9]+)*$
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cH0nY3/2). This pattern contains a `(?!.*\bwww\b)` lookahead that fails the whole match if there is a `www` somewhere inside the string and it has no digits or letters round it due to `\b` word boundaries.